# Screen grabber in Java: determine what executes first after closing JFrame. Windows and Linux differences

Tags: swing, jframe, cross-platform, java

I implemented a screen grabber. When the screen grabbing JFrame is closed, the portion of the screen that it covered moments ago is grabbed (captured). This works well in Windows using the standard Java from Oracle.

```
private void closeButtonPerformed() {
    Rectangle r = getBounds();
    setVisible(false);
    dispose();
    percept.grab_screen(r); // grab_screen(r) is in main program class
}
```

So, when the close button is pressed, the last position of JFrame is passed on to the grabber. getBounds() needs to execute while the JFrame is visible. Then the JFrame needs to be removed from the screen so that the grabber can capture the desktop underneath.

The same code does not work in Linux with OpenJDK and the result is that the grabber captures the content of the transient JFrame that defines the grabbing area.

Comment: And your question is..?

Comment: Oh... My question is how to correct this code to work in Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it is a little bit better to do setVisible(false); as stated in the original question, but to dispose(); of the grabber window later, in method percept.grab_screen(r);

A transparent window captures the screen content, but leave the thin edge visible. This is not the case in Windows.